# connecting -Vin and -Vout on a DC / DC converter

Tags: pcb, dc, ground, converter

I'm making a small board for a DC / DC converter.  Can I tie -Vin and -Vout together and think of them as GND?  Is there some noise advantage to keeping them separate?

Edit: the converter one of the [Murata UWE series linked here](http://power.murata.com/data/power/uwe.pdf), the UWE-12/6.

Comment: Generally speaking,  yes

Comment: In some industrial applications GND isolation is the sole purpose of the device.

Comment: @Harvard ok that makes sense.. this is a lipo battery powering a small computer dev kit, so I'm thinking GND isolation will be unnecessary.  thanks!

Comment: I feel like you are not really providing enough information. It is probably OK, but most IC's for consumer-grade devices don't even have separate -Vin and -Vout. So I am a bit curious what IC you are using. Maybe you should post a link to the datasheet and let someone take a closer look.

Comment: @mkeith -- edited my question to add a link to the datasheet.

Comment: That regulator might not be a good choice for a battery powered device. Will the battery be easy to disconnect? Or are you planning to leave it connected to the regulator all the time? The input current with no-load on the output is 90 mA for the high input voltage version (UWE-12/6-Q48) and 200 mA for the low input voltage version (UWE-12/6-Q12). But that would kind of be a separate question.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is fine to do if you don't need isolation between the input and output sides of the converter.  For the situation you describe (small battery-powered device) there's likely no EMI advantage to keeping them separated.